# Two actions for one variables PHP

Tags: php, variables

I want to have two actions for my one variables, here is the variables;

```
Header:('Location:http://localhost/portailinx/inscriptioncarosou.php')
unset($_SESSION['fb_token'])
```

I try with this :

```
$next = Header:('Location:http://localhost/portailinx/inscriptioncarosou.php') && unset($_SESSION['fb_token']);
```

but is not working.

Is not a form, it's just a simple variable for `facebookhelper->getLogoutURL`

Comment: Why do you wan't to save header in a variable?

Comment: Unset first, then header.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Makes no difference, does it?

Comment: Ah, I could be wrong. I'd have to test it to make absolutely sure. @NiettheDarkAbsol - However, I love it when OP's say *"but it's not working"*. Lack of [doing this...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [this...](http://www.google.com) ;-)

Comment: If the order mattered, then we wouldn't have to `exit` after setting the `Location` headeer, @Fred-ii- ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Exactly and you're right. It's just the way OP's code is setup; *incorrectly* ;-)

Comment: Order matters because of "&&"

Comment: @Rizier123 Facebook want a redirect URL. I cant just say the URL but I want to unset the token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all `unset` and after redirect user, eg:

```
// it is good practice to check that something is set before unset
if(isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])) unset($_SESSION['fb_token']);

// after unset can redirect the user
header('Location:http://localhost/portailinx/inscriptioncarosou.php');

// end the script run
exit;
```

Comment: Ok, I try like this : `function ($next) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])) unset($_SESSION['fb_token']);

// after unset can redirect the user
    header('Location:http://localhost/portailinx/inscriptioncarosou.php');

// end the script run
    exit;
};` but the link is not working. How can we insert script in a variable

Answer (score 1):

Unset before redirection, and fill there missing `;` at the end of commands.

```
unset ($_SESSION['fb_token']);
Header:('Location:http://localhost/portailinx/inscriptioncarosou.php');
```

`Header:` is somewhere probably defined as `header('Location: ' ...);`, if not, you meant this:

```
header ('Location: http://localhost/portailinx/inscriptioncarosou.php');
```

After redirect is good to end the script run, so add `exit` behind `header` function. The full script should be

```
unset ($_SESSION['fb_token']);
header ('Location: http://localhost/portailinx/inscriptioncarosou.php');
exit;
```

Comment: `Header:(` is a error! edit in `Header(`

Comment: It doesn't matter if the `unset` is before or after the `header`. If it did, there would be no need for `exit`, would there?

Answer (score -1):

Try it the other way.

It's called 'short-circuit' 
one-thing&&another
one-thing always happens first, then another.  So in your example the redirect happens, and the unset is never reached

Comment: `header` does not immediately end the script.

Comment: yes but it does return void - which causes && to fail.  Therefore never reaching the 'another' part.